# How can I ensure that the top level menu item has a CSS class of selected while clicking sun-menu?

Tags: asp.net, css, menu, tabs

I have **two ASP.NET 4.0 Menu controls** for **tabs and sub-tabs** & **one tree control for left side navigation** on a page.

I'm using the **selected CSS class** to ensure that the **selected tab/sub-tab/navigation** is in **different color**.

Whenever i select one of these control's item, **selected CSS applied on it** but parent selection **state lose**.

How can I ensure that the **top level menu item has a CSS class of selected when viewing a sub page**?

**Main Menu:**

```
<asp:SiteMapDataSource ID="SiteMapDataSource1" runat="server" ShowStartingNode="false" />

<asp:Menu ID="mainMenu" runat="server" Orientation="Horizontal" 
MaximumDynamicDisplayLevels="0" RenderingMode="Table"
DataSourceID="SiteMapDataSource1"
ViewStateMode="Enabled">
<StaticMenuStyle CssClass="menu"/>
<StaticMenuItemStyle CssClass="menuItem"/>
<StaticSelectedStyle CssClass="menuSelectedItem"/>
</asp:Menu>
```

**Sub Menu:**

```
<asp:SiteMapDataSource ID="SiteMapDataSource2" runat="server" ShowStartingNode="false"     StartingNodeOffset="1"/>

<asp:Menu ID="Menu1" runat="server" Orientation="Horizontal" 
MaximumDynamicDisplayLevels="0" RenderingMode="Table"
DataSourceID="SiteMapDataSource2"
ViewStateMode="Enabled">
<StaticMenuStyle CssClass="menu"/>
<StaticMenuItemStyle CssClass="menuItem"/>
<StaticSelectedStyle CssClass="menuSelectedItem"/>
</asp:Menu>
```

**Left Navigation:**

```
<asp:SiteMapDataSource ID="SiteMapDataSource3" runat="server" ShowStartingNode="false" 
StartingNodeOffset="2" />

<asp:TreeView ID="TreeView1" runat="server"
DataSourceID="SiteMapDataSource3" 
ExpandDepth="2" NodeIndent="0">
<ParentNodeStyle Font-Bold="False" />
<HoverNodeStyle ForeColor="#5555DD" />
<SelectedNodeStyle BackColor="GhostWhite"/>
<NodeStyle BackColor="LightSteelBlue"/>
</asp:TreeView>
```

**CSS:**

```
.menu
{
  background-color: black;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.menuItem td
{
  height: 24px;
  width: 120px; 
  background: url(Images/unselectedTab.jpg) no-repeat;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.menuSelectedItem td
{
 height: 24px;
 width: 120px;
 background: url(Images/selectedTab.jpg) no-repeat;
 text-align:center;
 vertical-align:middle;  
}
```

Comment: I do not think anyone will read as much code

Answer (score 0):

Did not read your code but according to me if you want to preserve parent menu item selected then you will have to check in your code that it is not getting removed. In your scripts there may be some code like -

```
$(this).parent().removeClass("selected");
```

Comment this line if it is present and check whether it works or not. If there is no such thing then you will have to apply class as below -

```
$(this).parent().addClass("selected");
```

Both of the above code line, you will find inside the function which is called on click of a menu.